# Checking if value in XML is undefined (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, xml

(I hope this question isn't too silly I am pretty much a novice at javascript)
I am parsing through an XML file for titles of books and I find each title by doing this.

```
(xml).find('title')[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue
```

right now, i is just a counter and the line is in a while loop. 
The problem that I am having is my condition for the while loop. I want to stop iterating when there are no more titles in the xml to look for. Right now I am getting exceptions each time the xml runs out of titles.

I suppose I want to make the condition of my while loop something along the lines of this:

```
(while(xml).find('title')[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue != undefined)
```

or even do a for loop along the lines of

```
for(i = 0; i < numberoftitles.length; i++)
```

but I have no idea how to actually get the numberoftitles, or the syntax for the while loop.

Comment: can you post the xml so that it will easy to get idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have the XML structure similar to below, and each BOOK element has TITLE in it:

```
<BOOK>
  <TITLE>ABC><TITLE/>
  ..
</BOOK>
<BOOK>
  <TITLE>PQR</TITLE>
  ..
</BOOK>
```

You can use the following to get all the TITLE values:

```
var tmp = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("TITLE");

for(var i = 0; i < tmp.length; i++)
{
  console.log(tmp[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
}
```